# Run .net application without installing it

Tags: .net, wpf, deployment, windows-7, .net-framework-version

I am creating an application meant to run on windows 7. I have researched on the internet and it says that Windows 7 comes with the .net framework 3.5. As a result I have set the target framework for my wpf application to use the .net framework 3.5

Is it safe to distribute this application without publishing it knowing that the users will have windows 7 or latter? Or should I create an installer?

The application works on most computers but it crashes on some. Could this crash be related because of not creating an installer and running the application directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of Windows OS and the .Net Framework that is installed on them [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx).
For your case:

> > Windows 7 (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 3.5.1 as an OS component.  This means you will get the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 plus a few post 3.5 SP1 bug fixes.  3.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the Programs and Features control panel.

The problem is that though it comes pre-installed it can be removed from the Control Panel (Highly not recommended as many applications use it and it would render them useless). It would be therefore, cautious of you if you do it by creating the installer and ensuring that it is already installed before running the appliction.
Regarding the crashing of the application nothing can be said for sure without checking its error logs (if any are present at the time of the crash) or debugging it on the machine it crashed (maybe .net 3.5 is not installed).